# c# datagridView , show total price

Tags: c#, datagridview, sum

[image]

Hi, I want to generate totalprice of each sold product.
My tables is as you see in attached image
It is working without total price. I mean working fine only with prtoductType and Totalsold.
But I want to show even total price of that sort of product.
My code is as following but not working and please help!

```
var result = (from s in db.SaleDetails
              join p in db.Product on s.ProductId equals p.ProductId
              group s by p.Description into g
              select new
              {
                ProductType = g.Key,
                TolatlSold = g.Count(),
                TotalPrice = g.Count() *//Times what ?? I tried g.Count()*p.price but I can't
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: `g.Sum(x => x.Price)`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov thank you very much. It's working as I wanted. I don't how to vote your answer. Can you just write it as answer by Writing code.. maybe? I have voted it as userful.